# Import Export Module in nodejs

Tags: node.js, function, export

In Nodejs, i created a function in th path /js

```
var myfunction=function(param1){
}
exports.myfunctionA=myfunctionA
```

In the path routes, I want call this function 
myfunctionA=require('./js/myFunctionA')
But I have a message:
Unhandled rejection TypeError: myfunctionA is not a function

Thanks for your help,
Mdouke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo in function name

```
var myfunctionA=function(param1){}
exports.myfunctionA=myfunctionA
```

If this file is named `functionA.js` then You can include a `module` by

```
var moduleA = require('./js/functionA')
```

In this module You have a `functionA`. You can access to this function by

```
var functionA = moduleA.functionA
```

or simpliest way

```
var functionA = require('./js/moduleA').functionA
```

If you module only export a one function, then named this file `functionA.js` and write

```
exports = function(){}
```

and access to this function by

```
functionA = require('./js/functionA')
```

I hope I help.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It!s not the problem. If a fonction is declared in a folder, normailly it's possible to import in a other folder whith the declaration require('../js/myfunctionA') ?

Comment: I improved the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the content of your file in js path as follow

```
exports.myfunctionA = function(param1){
}
```

after that in route path, you require:

```
var myfunction = require('./js/myFunctionA');
```

and use it:

```
myfunction.myfunctionA();
```